# formula field to update date field based on condition

Tags: apex

I have a date field in case object `CaseStatusDate__c`. I need to update this field to `NOW()` if the case status is in open/reopen and i need to make it  empty/null if the state changes.

Here is my formula field:

```
IF(OR( 
    ISPICKVAL(Status,"Open"), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status,"Reopened") 
), 
NOW() , 
NULL)
```

when i click on case and edit it for the first time the date field changes ,but i need to do it two times for the date field to appear on 'open' state . i.e first time works fine,second time when i do update on same feild i need to do it twice....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

1. AND( NOT(ISNULL(CaseStatusDate__c)), OR( ISPICKVAL(status__c,
   'Open'), ISPICKVAL(status__c, 'Reopened') ) )
2. ( ( ISPICKVAL( status__c , 'Open') ||  ISPICKVAL( status__c ,
   'Reopened')) && (NOT(ISBLANK(CaseStatusDate__c)))

   )

   **Both work for me**